# Can't link libtiff

Tags: c++, libtiff

I'm trying to build a C++ program using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
extern "C" {
     #include "libtiff/libtiff/tiffio.h"
}

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
string imageName("410.tif"); // start with a default

                             // If there is an argument, read it in as the name of the image
if (argc > 1)
{
    imageName = argv[1];
}

// Open the TIFF file using libtiff
TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(imageName.c_str(), "r");

// Create a matrix to hold the tif image in
Mat image;

// check the tif is open
if (tif) {
    do {
        unsigned int width, height;
        uint32* raster;

        // get the size of the tiff
        TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);
        TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height);

        uint npixels = width * height; // get the total number of pixels

        raster = (uint32*)_TIFFmalloc(npixels * sizeof(uint32)); // allocate temp memory (must use the tiff library malloc)
        if (raster == NULL) // check the raster's memory was allocaed
        {
            TIFFClose(tif);
            cerr << "Could not allocate memory for raster of TIFF image" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        // Check the tif read to the raster correctly
        if (!TIFFReadRGBAImage(tif, width, height, raster, 0))
        {
            TIFFClose(tif);
            cerr << "Could not read raster of TIFF image" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        image = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4); // create a new matrix of w x h with 8 bits per channel and 4 channels (RGBA)

                                             // itterate through all the pixels of the tif
        for (uint x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (uint y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                uint32& TiffPixel = raster[y*width + x]; // read the current pixel of the TIF
                Vec4b& pixel = image.at<Vec4b>(Point(y, x)); // read the current pixel of the matrix
                pixel[0] = TIFFGetB(TiffPixel); // Set the pixel values as BGRA
                pixel[1] = TIFFGetG(TiffPixel);
                pixel[2] = TIFFGetR(TiffPixel);
                pixel[3] = TIFFGetA(TiffPixel);
            }

        _TIFFfree(raster); // release temp memory
                           // Rotate the image 90 degrees couter clockwise
        image = image.t();
        flip(image, image, 0);
        imshow("TIF Image", image); // show the image
        waitKey(0); // wait for anykey before displaying next
    } while (TIFFReadDirectory(tif)); // get the next tif
    TIFFClose(tif); // close the tif file
}
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I include libtiff but when I try to compile I get the following error:

> LNK2019   reference to the external symbol _TIFFmalloc not resolved in
>   the function

The error is extended to "_TIFFfree,TIFFClose, TIFFGetField, TIFFReadDirectory, TIFFReadRGBAImage, TIFFOpen" (I posted only one to be easier).

I tried to search on google about this problem and I think that this is caused by a linking problem. A lot of people told that I should add "libtiff.lib" in the "input" section of Visual Studio project's properties but I have no libtiff.lib in the library I downloaded from the official source.

I'm using the 4.0.4 version of the library.

Comment: As these are for portability do you need to provide these or link in a version for your platform?

Comment: Also do you have a prototype for then. Perhaps they should be C prototypes.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw if they weren't C prototypes already wouldn't the error message show a decorated name?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, the problem is that these aren't available in C++?  How am I supposed to fix it? I tried to add extern "C" too but nothing is changed.

Comment: @Davide57 You didn't link with libtiff.lib, what did you link with and how did you do it?

Comment: @Davide57 It's pretty clear now that you aren't linking with the tiff library. **All** the functions you are using are unresolved. It's not enough to `#include` you must also link. Reread the documentation.

Comment: @john Yes, but as I told, I can't link because there's no a libtiff.lib in the library. Is there another way to link the library on Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @Davide57 Maybe you got a source code only distribution and you are expected to build the library yourself? I don't know, I can't see what you are lookig at.

Comment: @john I downloaded the 4.0.4 version from this:
https://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/
I tried with other versions too but I can't find this libtiff.lib file anywhere. Could be that the file has a different extension?

Comment: There are two Makefile (.in and .am) how should I use them to link the library? @john

Comment: @Davide57 That's a source only release with a Unix build process.You might be able to build it on Windows if you download something like Cygwin. But really I think you'd be better off looking for a Windows distribution of libtiff.

Comment: @john I need to use it on Windows...

Comment: @Davide57 Is this what you want? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm

Comment: Yes @john, now using this library I got the .lib file and I can link it but the problem is that I got the problem:
Notice LNK4272 the 'x86' type of the library computer conflicts with the 'x64' type of the target computer ImageManipulation C: \ Program Files (x86) \ GnuWin32 \ lib \ libtiff.lib 1
The platform solution is set on x64 and I must maintain this because of openCV...

Comment: @Davide57 Well maybe another library? It seems libtiff is not for you.

Comment: @john I successfully added libtiff and I found openCV with 64bit (https://datapacket.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/3.4.2/opencv-3.4.2-vc14_vc15.exe)
So I can use it on x86 mode but in this openCV version there's not a global.lib and when I try to add all the .lib files I get the following errors:

Comment: >Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: char * __thiscall cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@String@cv@@AAEPADI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::String(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0String@cv@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Comment: 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class cv::String const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: @Davide57 A guess but do you still have the old OpenCV installation? It seems like you might be using the header files from your old OpenCV but the library files from your new OpenCV. Delete the old OpenCV and try again, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

TIFF is a C library, while your program is in C++, C++ and C have different linking ABIs.

When you use a C library from a C++ source code you should usually do something like:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "libtiff/libtiff/tiffio.h"
}
```

... to signal C++ that that symbols follow the C ABI.

**NOTE**: Many widely used C libraries include C++ conditional preprocessor checks inside their headers to avoid this problem, something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/* Actual header content */
extern int do_something(void); 
extern int do_something_else(const char*); 
/* ... */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#end
```

This is not the case for libtiff.

Comment: I'm sure you are right but why is _TIFFmalloc the only unresolved.

Comment: I tried to add what you said but the problem persists.
Anyway @john the problem is extended to all the "_" but I posted only one.

Comment: @Davide57 Just a guess but maybe the "_" functions are defined in another library, one that you aren't linking with?

Comment: @john The problem is on "_TIFFMalloc, _TIFFfree, TIFFClose, TIFFGetField, TIFFReadDirectory, TIFFReadRGBAImage, TIFFOpen". I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Using the following library:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm
I can include correctly libtiff but the problem is that this library is 64bit and openCV is 32bit. So I get the following error:

> LNK4272 the 'x86' type of the library computer conflicts with the 'x64' type of the target computer ImageManipulation C: \ Program Files (x86) \ GnuWin32 \ lib \ libtiff.lib 1

The platform solution in Visual Studio is set on x64 because if I turn it on x86 openCV doesn't work.